# To get sum values of other columns based on first column values

Tags: matlab

An excel file contains 5 columns; first column contains year (1987 to 2080), second column contains month, third column contains days, fourth and fifth column contain values. I would like to get the sum values of columns four and five according to year in column one. For example, I would like to get the sum values of column four and five for year 1987, then 1988, then 1989...so on.!
[Example of data file is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akSEw.png)

I have tried the following code considering that each year contains 365 days.

```
n=1;
for i=1:365:size(data,1)
    Total(n,:) = sum(data(i:i+365-1,:));
    n=n+1;
end
```

But the problem is that not all the years contain 365  days. Some of them (e.g. 1988, 1992) contain 366 days in a year as they are leap year. In those cases, the sum results become incorrect.

Looking for your help to get the sum values of columns 4 and 5 according to the year in column 1.

It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: much faster solution at the end!**

---

It can be done as follows with one line for each column:

```
% some example data
years = ceil(1987:0.3:2080)';
months = randi(12,numel(years),1);
days = randi(30,numel(years),1);
values = randi(42,numel(years),2);
% data similar to yours;
data = [ years months days values ];
```

That would be the easy readable long way:

```
% years
y = data(:,1)
% unique years
uy = unique(y);
% for column 4
C4 = arrayfun(@(x) sum( data(y == x, 4) ), uy )
% for column 5
C5 = arrayfun(@(x) sum( data(y == x, 5) ), uy )
```

or just short in one line per column:

```
C4 = arrayfun(@(x) sum( data( (data(:,1) == x), 4) ), unique(data(:,1)) )
```

returning a `94x1` double array with all sums for all 94 unique years of the example data.

If you want to arrange it somehow you could do it as follows:

```
summary = [uy, C4, C5]
```

returning something like:

```
summary =         %//sum of      sum of
                     column 4    column 5

        1987           3           3
        1988          40          40
        1989          56          56
        1990          96          96
        1991          54          54
        1992          15          15
        1993          73          73
        1994          42          42
        1995          66          66
        1996          56          56
        ...
```

You could also do all columns at once. Already for just 2 column it should be 50% faster.

```
cols = 4:5;
C = cell2mat( arrayfun(@(x) sum( data(y == x, cols),1 ), uy,'uni',0 ) )
```

The problem with that solution is, that you have a matrix of about `30000x5` size, and for every unique years it will apply the indexing on the whole matrix to "search" for the current year which is summed up. But actually there is an in-built function doing exactly that:

---

**A simpler and much faster solution you can achieve using** [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[~,~, i_uy] = unique(data(:,1));
C4 = accumarray(i_uy,data(:,4));
C5 = accumarray(i_uy,data(:,5));
```

Comment: Many thanks @thewaywewalk!!...greatly appreciated for giving other options as well

Comment: @shawpnik: Please have a look at my edit, I posted another solution, which fits your needs better and is more than an order faster!